# How to get webelement size within a parent webelement?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have several parents , and questions under it.

> ```
> p1 -> Q1 ,Q2, Q3 
>
> P2 -> Q1, Q2, Q3
>
> P3 -> Q1, Q2 , Q3
> ```

I am trying to get the number of questions in P1 and using below code. 
It is returning all the Questions count. 
Parent is a webelement list.

```
int x= parent.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("childrens xpath"))).size();
```

Other Functions like click or get text are working.

Answer (score 0):

When you said Webelement size Did  you mean the length and width of the element?You can get the size of the elements in C# like below.

```
//Return the child element size
IEnumerable<Size> Elementsizes =browser.FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format("ParentElementXpath")).Select(e => e.Size);
```

The above code returns the list of sizes of the child elements.

Update : To get the count of the elements in parent element, the below is the code snippet.

```
int elementCount = browser.FindElements(By.XPath(s"ParentElementXpath")).Count
```

browser above is the instance of the webdriver.

Comment: I want the number of Questions for each parent.